# JSONDecodeError When using YFinance for downloading data

Tags: python, json, yfinance

I am getting the following error when I am trying to download data using yfinance library. The strange fact is that this is the code I run all days to download data. I was thinking of a server error but I really don't know.
This morning it gives me this warning that doesn't stop the code to run but it actually stops data from downloading.
Do you have any guess?
Thank you very much

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
tickers = ["BTC-USD", "XLM-USD", "XRP-USD", "XMR-USD", "LTC-USD"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
ohlcv = {}
start = dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(3000)
end = dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(0)
for ticker in tickers:
    df[ticker] = yf.download(ticker,start,end, interval = "1wk")['Adj Close'].dropna()

Exception in thread Thread-30:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multitasking\__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 167, in _download_one_threaded
    actions, period, interval, prepost, proxy, rounding)
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 182, in _download_one
    rounding=rounding, many=True)
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 155, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\LorenzoFancelli\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as I updated my virtualenv from Python 3.7 to 3.8. Uninstalling yfinance and reinstalling it solved the issue.
Check this post too: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/318